# Error when I get a view in Openui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I retrieve a view by

```
this.app.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview("operationDetail", "appIntra.detail.operationDetail"));
```

but I have this error in console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/ZWebapp/appIntra/detail/operationDetail.view.xml 404 (Not Found) sap-ui-core.js:27
    Uncaught Error: resource appIntra/detail/operationDetail.view.xml could not be loaded from ./appIntra/detail/operationDetail.view.xml. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors.
```

Comment: So... Did you check the path? Did you check the console for HTTP errors?

Comment: i have this problem after i changed the name of the view from Operation to operation. I think it is a cache problem.. i use Chrome.. 
How i set chrome to not sotre a cache?

Comment: Did you rename the file on your server?

Comment: (I rename all view to first letter lowercase)

Comment: Check, that the name of the view is equal in your view file and in your call statement. Using Chrome you can easilly turn of the cache when the console is open. To do so just click on the settings button in the developer console and select distale cache while open. This often solves many problems